# Effect of Altered Testosterone Levels in a Human Subspecies?

Tags: biology, evolution

What factors would cause a human subspecies to develop so that the males have lower levels of testosterone and/or females have raised levels relative to the human norm? What kind of effect would this have on their physiology, especially in regards to appearance and reproductive ability?

Comment: Could you provide numbers? Overweight men that don't work out and so on could lower it, but maybe not as low as you'd like?

Comment: Human populations have different testosterone levels already. Human populations have very different physical appearances already. "Subspecies" implies a certain level of reproductive isolation; humans don't have subspecies, and it's hard to see how they could arise.

Comment: These are two different questions. I wonder if you could ask them separately?

Comment: High levels of testosterone in women can lead to a number of health problems including infertility. Would you accept those as the answer, or would you like to handwave them away?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your first question of why such a change might occur let’s start with your second question of what changing testosterone levels might do. By testosterone I’m going to assume you are interested in all of the androgens, such as dihydrotestosterone, and are simply referencing the most well-known.

Androgens are responsible for nearly every sexually dimorphic trait in humans. The differences between men and women in the areas of hair growth, breast size, muscle mass, skeletal strength, fat deposition, external genitalia, and even behavior are all the result of androgens. This can be easily seen in people with Complete Androgen Insensitivity Syndrome (NSFW wikipedia link) [(CAIS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_androgen_insensitivity_syndrome). This disorder is caused by a non-functional Androgen Receptor gene resulting in individuals having effectively no androgen signalling. XY individuals with CAIS develop testes that produce androgens but without a receptor the androgens have no effect on the rest of the body. These individuals present entirely as women and tend to self-identify as heterosexual women despite having internal testes. Androgen Insensitivity Syndrome is not always complete. Partial Androgen Insensitivity Syndrome (NSFW wikipedia link) [(PAIS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_androgen_insensitivity_syndrome) can lead to intersex individuals with mixtures of both male and female traits.

So it’s clear that the level of androgens (or their efficacy) in the body can produce phenotypes that are fully male, fully female, and anything in between. Since you asked specifically about reproduction low-enough androgen levels in males and high enough androgen levels in females will result in total infertility. However, since this is in theory a phenomenon evolving in a natural population it’s reasonable to assume that the changes will not be so drastic as to hinder fertility. Thus males must retain enough androgen signalling to produce viable sperm and females must have low enough levels to permit the formation of functioning wombs otherwise this population will never exist. That’s still a lot of wiggle room though to influence the appearance and behavior in your population.

It’s important to point out at this time that sexual development and dimorphism isn’t nearly as simple as tallying up how much androgen signalling an individual has. There are multiple different androgens that perform different tasks in different parts of the body and at different points during development as well as estrogenic factors that promote various aspects of female sexual development. What this means for your question then is that individuals don’t simply exist on a one dimensional male-female axis but rather can possess some feminine traits and other masculine traits dependent on which hormones are functioning when and where.

So the answer to your second question of what changing sex hormones might do to men and women is really anything you’d like to have happen. You can have men and women have similar average heights and strengths, or taller, physically stronger women and shorter, physically weaker men. Behavior, hair growth, breast size, fat deposition, etc. can all be shifted between the male and female extremes independently of each other in theory.

Now, to your first question: Why might these changes occur? One of the most potent selective forces in evolutionary theory is sexual selection or mate choice. Essentially, if the opposite sex finds a trait attractive that trait will spread rapidly in the population. If for example we imagine that this human subspecies developed a matriarchal social structure in which female individuals’ stature, strength, aggressive tendencies correlated with reproductive success while in males an opposite selection pressure was applied then over the course of perhaps dozens or hundreds of generations this could lead to a swap of some traditional sexually dimorphic traits. The time and magnitude of the change will depend on the strength of the selection pressure.